# Is there a simple way to use twitter-bootstrap-responsive, but avoid the stacking in a particular case?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to get a particular form of responsive design.  I am using twitter-bootstrap and their responsive css but am having trouble avoiding the 'auto-stacking' feature.

I am trying to achieve the following display when viewed in desktop:

[image]

and similarly in mobile I essentially want the same layout but with the buttons squashed, rather than stacked. My html (which stacks when the screen gets smaller) is as follows:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "span12">
        <select class = "span2">
            <option> </option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class = "input input-large span10" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "row">
    <div class = "span4">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "span4">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">2</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "span4">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "span3">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">A</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "span3">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "span3">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "span3">
        <button class = "btn btn-block btn-large btn-dial">D</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can achieve this without hacking the css?

Comment: The best way is to add a class such as 'no-stack' and style accordingly to override the default CSS.

Comment: So it seems - any clues as to which css needs to be overridden to stop the stacking and start the shrinking? If I just remove the responsive css file it simply makes it so teh screen is a fixed width - it doesn't start teh shrinking effect I'm after.

Comment: Use the web inspector to find the styles that are causing the undesired affect. Then, reverse those styles with your 'no-stack' class. For example, Float: none, becomes Float:left.